# Prevent cache sharing between Rails apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached

I have an issue while deploying two Rails (3) applications on the same server (Nginx w. Passenger 4). The cache guide states:

> If you're running multiple Ruby on Rails server processes (which is
>   the case if you're using mongrel_cluster or Phusion Passenger), then
>   your Rails server process instances won't be able to share cache data
>   with each other.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-memorystore

But if I fire up the console for both of these apps and do Rails.cache.write and then Rails.cache.read on the other, the data is shared.

I tried to add a namespace to the cache configuration, but it still shares after doing that. I have the applications running on two different user accounts as well. What do I need to do to prevent these application from exposing their caches to each other?

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html#activesupport-cache-store

Comment: What is your `config.cache_store` set to? If it's `:file_store` and they're both using the same directory then they'd end up sharing the cache. If they're on memory store then they can't because each rails process get's it's own instance of the memory cache.

Comment: config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

Comment: I switched to "dalli" and setting a namespace there seems to have done the trick and I guess that will be my solution. Seems to be the recommended way anyway.